# Firebase authentication for different kinds of users

Tags: android, firebase

I'm working on a Doctor-on-Demand kind of application and I want to use firebase for the project. I have 3 types of users and Apps:

- Patients
- Doctors
- Admin

What are workaround on this, for example for the case of authentication each have their own custom fields.

Comment: You need to group them in your database  by id in tables Admins, Doctors and Patients.

Comment: Do you want database structure for above user types ?

Comment: @AntonisRadz would this be different tables or same table?

Comment: @Ashish Yes that would be more helpful

Comment: It could be same table with different user Role column

Comment: You may be interested by reading the following [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) which explains how to build a module which allows end-users with a specific Admin role creating other users and assigning them other specific user roles. *(disclaimer, I'm the author)*

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear why you want to use firebase and for what purpose. I mean how you want to use firebase here. Please give some more detail about it.

Answer (score 0):

Set the value like `is_admin == 1` and `is_doctors == 2` and `is_patients == 3` and please give some more detail about it.